# A RESTful Web Service with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest

I have been working on my first Web Service application, and I need to earse/replace `ModelAndView`.

I want to keep the webpages separately from the application files, and suggestions?

> **class ModelAndView**
>
> Holder for both Model and View in the web MVC framework. Note that these are entirely distinct. This class merely holds both to make it possible for a controller to return both model and view in a single return value.
>
> Represents a model and view returned by a handler, to be resolved by a DispatcherPortlet. The view can take the form of a String view name which will need to be resolved by a ViewResolver object; alternatively a view object can be specified directly. The model is a Map, allowing the use of multiple objects keyed by name.

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all remove below code from controller layer:

```
 @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
         CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new                    CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10240000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
```

Make a java file say ProductConfig annotate it with @Config and include all configuration method like multipartResolver() in it.

2) Coming to your question,you can sent the result as JSON response instead of 
using ModelAndView
example:

```
@RequestMapping("getProductById/{productId}")
    public @ResponseBody getProductById(@PathVariable(value = "productId") String productId) {
        Product product = productService.getProductById(productId);
        return product;
}
```

Now this API with return a json response.

On the front end ,you can use some framework like angular js.
Angular provides features such as routing which can help you to navigate.
Ideally all frontend navigation should not be handled at java layer

Answer (score 0):

If your plan is to run a separate server for the front end then make sure you [enable CORS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/).

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
        }
    };
}
```